# How to lookup a public IP address and write only the IP address to a text file?

Tags: networking, command-line, dns

I have looked and found the following line of code which works fine but when run in a batch file nothing happens.

```
for /f "skip=4 usebackq tokens=2" %a in (`nslookup microsoft.com 8.8.8.8`) do echo %a > C:\ip.txt
```

Can someone please let me know, obviously completely new to scripting but trying.

Comment: what IP do you want? IP of the machine where your code is running? Or IP of a known host?

Answer (score 1):

You will need double % inside .bat files
Btw, probably you want `>>` (adding every result to the file) instead of `>` (overwriting the file with the last result)

Answer (score 0):

**when run in a batch file nothing happens.**

You **should** get an error message like the following:

```
C:\test>cat foo.cmd
for /f "skip=4 usebackq tokens=2" %a in (`nslookup microsoft.com 8.8.8.8`) do echo %a > ip.txt
C:\test>foo
a was unexpected at this time.

C:\test>for /f "skip=4 usebackq tokens=2" a > ip.txt
```

This error is because you need to use `%%` instead of `%` inside a batch file.

Reference [FOR - Conditionally perform a command several times.](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) :

> **syntax-FOR-Files**
>
> `FOR %%parameter IN (set) DO command`
>
> ...
>
> `FOR` Parameters
>
> The first parameter has to be defined using a single character, for example the letter `G`.
>
> `FOR %%G IN` ...
>
> If you are using the `FOR` command at the command line rather than in a
>   batch program, use just one percent sign: `%G` instead of `%%G`.

So in your case, if you want to use the `for` command inside a batch (`cmd`) file then each <kbd>%</kbd> needs to be replaced by <kbd>%%</kbd> as follows:

```
for /f "skip=4 usebackq tokens=2" %%a in (`nslookup microsoft.com 8.8.8.8`) do echo %%a > C:\ip.txt
```